How to specify the system for noncrossing partitions (as a function)
I am interested in the noncrossing partitions.
Here using the pentagon as an example: 

If I number the corners

how can I specify a function that tells me which corner I need to connect to which other corners in order to create the cases in the image above?

If $a, b$ are two numbers in $S = {1,2,\dots, n}$, with $a < b$, let $(a,b) = {k \in S : a < k < b}$ and $(b,a) = {k \in S : k < a\text{ or }k > b}$. Then if $a,b$ are together in a partition set, the other partitions must be subsets of $(a,b)$ or of $(b,a)$. They cannot contain elements of both. Any partition whose sets always satisfy that rule will be non-crossing.
